# Code runs slowly parsing large xml files w/ python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, large-files

I've got 2 very large xml files that hold different data for the same place/building/room combinations.  I am currently using python etree parse on the first large file then looping through it to extract the place/building/room ids (along with other information) to then use those ids to loop through the second large xml file (same structure as the first) which I'm currenlty using lxml iterparse to find and extract the Place element in the second file pertainent to the specific place from the first file.  Then it loops through that place element to find the pertinent data   It works, but it continues to get slower and slower as I loop through further and further into the first file.

I've done everything I can to clear() elements not pertainent in the iterparse of the second large file which helped, but I've got 5000 places to loop through and the first 100 are processed very quickly (less than a minute) then the next 400 take 30 minutes, and so on.  After 15 hours I was at about 4000 facilities and moving very slowly.  I suspect the parsing of one of the files is holding too much data.

Here's the simplified code (sorry I couldn't simplify it further) with genericified xml.

```
largefile1 = "largefile1.xml"
largefile2 = "largeFile2.xml"

ptree = ET.parse (largefile1)
proot = ptree.getroot()

o = open('output.txt', 'w')

def get_place_elem(pplaceid,largefile2):
    Placenode = ET.iterparse(Largefile2, events=("end",), tag='Place')

    for event, Place in Placenode:
        for PlaceId in Place.findall('PlaceIdentification'):
            placeid = PlaceId.find('PlaceIdentifier').text
                if placeid == pplaceid:
                    del Placenode
                    return Place
        Place.clear()
        while Place.getprevious() is not None:
            del Place.getparent()[0]
    del Placenode

def getfacdata(pplaceid,pbuildid,proomid,Place):

    for Build in Place.findall('Building'):
        euid = ' '
        for BuildId in Build.findall('BuildingIdentification'):
            bid = BuildId.find('Identifier').text
        if bid ==pbid:
            for Room in Build.findall('Room'):
                roomid = ' '
                for RoomId in Room.findall('RoomIdentification'):
                    roomid = RoomId.find('Identifier').text
                    if roomid == proomid:

                        ...Collect data from Room element...
                        ... do some simple math with if statements
                        return data; # list of 15 data values

for pPlace in proot.findall('.//Place'):
    for pPlaceId in pPlace.findall('PlaceIdentification'):
        pplaceid = pPlaceId.find('PlaceIdentifier').text
            if placeid == pplaceid:
                placecnt += 1
                #... get some data

    for pBuild in pPlace.findall('Buidling'):
        for pBuildId in pBuild.findall('BuildingIdentification'):
            pbid = pBuildId.find('Identifier').text

        for pRoom in pBuild.findall('Room'):
                for pRoomId in pRoom.findall('RoomIdentification'):
                    proomid = pRoom.find('Identifier').text

                    if prevpplaceid != pplaceid:
                        if placecnt != 1:Place.clear()
                            Place = get_fac_elem(pplaceid,largefile2)
                            prevpplaceid = pplaceid

                    data = getfacdata(pplaceid,pbid,proomid,Place)

                    #...Collect data from Room element...
                    #... do some simple math with if statements    
                    writer = csv.writer(o)
                    writer.writerow( ( # data from proom and from 'data' list from processing largefile2 in csv format##))
                    break    
    prevpplaceid = pplaceid


o.close()
```

genericified xml

```
 <Payload>
<Place>
    <PlaceName>Place1</PlaceName>
    <PlaceStatusCode>OP</PlaceStatusCode>
    <PlaceStatusCodeYear>2011</PlaceStatusCodeYear>
    <PlaceComment/>
    <PlaceIdentification>
        <PlaceIdentifier>id001</PlaceIdentifier>
        <StateAndCountyFIPSCode>77702</StateAndCountyFIPSCode>
    </PlaceIdentification>
    <PlaceAddress>
        <LocationAddressText>111 Main</LocationAddressText>
        <SupplementalLocationText/>
        <LocalityName>City1</LocalityName>
        <LocationAddressStateCode>State1</LocationAddressStateCode>
        <LocationAddressPostalCode>12345</LocationAddressPostalCode>
        <LocationAddressCountryCode>USA</LocationAddressCountryCode>
    </PlaceAddress>
    <PlaceGeographicCoordinates>
        <LatitudeMeasure>88.888</LatitudeMeasure>
        <LongitudeMeasure>-99.999</LongitudeMeasure>
    </PlaceGeographicCoordinates>
    <Building>
        <BuildingDescription>Building1</BuildingDescription>
        <BuildingTypeCode>999</BuildingTypeCode>
        <BuildingIdentification>
            <Identifier>Building1</Identifier>
        </BuildingIdentification>
        <Room>
            <RoomIdentification>
                <Identifier>Room1</Identifier>
            </RoomIdentification>
            ... More data ...
        </Room>
        <Room>
            <RoomIdentification>
                <Identifier>Room2</Identifier>
            </RoomIdentification>
            ... More data ...
        </Room>
        ...
    </Building>
    <Building>
        <BuildingDescription>Building2</BuildingDescription>
        <BuildingTypeCode>999</BuildingTypeCode>
        <BuildingIdentification>
            <Identifier>Building2</Identifier>
        </BuildingIdentification>
        <Room>
            <RoomIdentification>
                <Identifier>Room1</Identifier>
            </RoomIdentification>
            ... More data ...
        </Room>
        <Room>
            <RoomIdentification>
                <Identifier>Room4</Identifier>
            </RoomIdentification>
            ... More data ...
        </Room>
        ...
    </Building>
    ...
</Place>
<Place>
    ...
</Place>
```

Comment: Could you indent your code please?

Comment: Use a python profiling tool to locate the hotspots and where the memory is being consumed. This pulls up enough results to get you started: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+profiling

Comment: I've done my best re-indenting the code (tabs in Python code are not a good idea, really) but it looks like there are some errors still. Can you verify and correct?

Comment: made edit to indents and made other edits that were overlooked when I was trying to clean (and genericfy) the code for posting.  Code actually works, I just looking for suggestions related to the efficient use of memory when parsing either using iterparse or regular parse.  I will try the profiling suggested and relay what I find.  Thanks!!!

Comment: looks like I've lost all indenting now.  No time right now to fix.  Will alittle later this afternoon.

Comment: I am sorry... I can't seem to indent anything now.  I'm going to see what the profiling shows me.  Thanks for the help...

Comment: I used the profiling tool Marcin suggested and determine my largefile2 was the problem, it just took too long to cycle through it.  I've split it into multiple files and the code is now running much much faster.  Sorry for any confusion yesterday, I was having serious trouble with the indenting yesterday, seem to be better today.  Thanks to all for their time!!!!